# How to fix Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python

**I try to build my first game with an Youtube tutorial but I get this Error and I don't know how to fix it. Please help :)**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Python Tut\FirstGame\FirstGame.py", line 144, in 
    bullet.x += bullet.vel
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'

**My Code:**

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 480))

pygame.display.set_caption('First Game')

#load character images
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R1.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R2.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R3.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R4.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R5.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R6.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R7.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R8.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L1.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L2.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L3.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L4.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L5.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L6.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L7.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L8.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/standing.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Character
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.standing = True
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)

def draw(self, window):
    if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        self.walkCount = 0
    if not(self.standing):
        if self.left:
            window.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            window.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
    else:
        if self.right:
            window.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
        else:
            window.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
    self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 11, 29, 52)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)


class projectile(object):
    def __init__ (self, x, y, radius, facing, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, window):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)


#Enemy
class enemy(object):
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R1E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R2E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R3E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R4E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R5E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R6E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R7E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R8E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R9E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R10E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/R11E.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L1E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L2E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L3E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L4E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L5E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L6E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L7E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L8E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L9E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L10E.png'), 
pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Python Tut/FirstGame/L11E.png')]

def __init__ (self, x, y, width, height, end):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.end = end
    self.path = [self.x, self.end]
    self.walkCount = 0
    self.vel = 3
    self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)

def draw(self, window):
    self.move()
    if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33:
        self.walkCount = 0

    if self.vel > 0:
        window.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount //3], (self.x, self.y))
        self.walkCount += 1
    else:
        window.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount //3], (self.x, self.y))
        self.walkCount += 1
    self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)


def move(self):
    if self.vel > 0:
        if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
            self.x += self.vel
        else:
            self.vel = self.vel * -1
            self.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
            self.x += self.vel
        else:
            self.vel = self.vel * -1
            self.walkCount = 0


def hit(self):
    print('hit')


def redrawGameWindow():
    window.blit(bg, (0,0))
    man.draw(window)
    goblin.draw(window)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)

    pygame.display.update()


#mainloop
man = player(200, 400, 64, 64)
goblin = enemy(100, 400, 64, 64, 460)
bullets = []
run = True
while run:
   clock.tick(27)

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

for bullet in bullets:
    if bullet.y - bullet.radius < goblin.hitbox[1] + goblin.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > 
    goblin.hitbox[1]:
        if bullet.x + bullet.radius > goblin.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < 
        goblin.hitbox[0] + goblin.hitbox[2]:
            goblin.hit()
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    if bullet.x < 600 and bullet.x > 0:
        bullet.x += bullet.vel
    else:
        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

#Movement
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    if man.left:
        facing = -1
    else:
        facing = 1

    if len(bullets) < 5:
        bullets.append(projectile(round(man.x + man.width //2), round(man.y + man.height //2), 6, 
        (0,0,0), facing))

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
    man.x -= man.vel
    man.left = True
    man.right = False
    man.standing = False
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 600 - man.width - man.vel:
    man.x += man.vel
    man.right = True
    man.left = False
    man.standing = False
else:
    man.standing = True
    man.walkCount = 0

if not(man.isJump):
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        man.isJump = True
        man.walkCount = 0
else:
    if man.jumpCount >= -10:
        neg = 1
        if man.jumpCount < 0:
            neg = -1
        man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
        man.jumpCount -= 1
    else:
        man.isJump = False
        man.jumpCount = 10

redrawGameWindow()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Congrats on your first post! To get any help on SO, some evidence of effort is generally advised. What did you try to debug this issue so far? Add print(bullet.x, bullet.vel) on the line before bullet.x += bullet.vel and see what you see!

Comment: This is what I see 212 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: Okie. So clearly, x coordinate are '212' and velocity is a tuple with lot's of zeroes! You probably will need to do a running average on the velocity tuple to come up with the displacement in 'x' to be added.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging, any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your object `bullet.vel` is a tuple (according to your error). `bullet` is a `tuple` too and `bullet.x` is an integer. You can not add a `tuple` to an `int`. So you have to access the individual member of your `tuple` and add this to your `int`.
This will look like this for example:

```
bullet.x += bullet.vel.x
```

I don´t know if your `tuple` `vel` does contain any member with the name `x`, because you don´t specify this `tuple`, so you have to change the name to the correct one.